# How can a Solana Rust smart contract get block height or Unix time?

Tags: rust, blockchain, unix-timestamp, solana

I know how to pass the current Unix time from the frontend:

web3.js:

```js
anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY
```

Rust:

```rust
let current_time = ctx.accounts.clock.unix_timestamp;
```

I do not want that. I need the smart contract itself to get the current time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using anchor

```
let now_ts = Clock::get().unwrap().unix_timestamp;
```

You will need to pass in the system program account

Comment: Hi thank you. I figured it out with your code and use solana_program::sysvar::clock::Clock;
is that what you meant by "system program account"?

Comment: you can set this account in your context `pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,` and pass in `systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the sysvar data examples at the top of this page: https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/sysvars

You have two ways from the smart contract / on-chain program:

```
let clock = Clock::get();
```

or you pass in the account to the instruction from the outside, then deserialize the clock from that account:

```
let clock_sysvar_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
let clock = Clock::from_account_info(&clock_sysvar_info)?;
```